# PowerAutomate extract the reception date from an email

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I have a document library in SharePoint, where a user can add a email message (in .EML, .MSG etc).

I have added a custom column "Received", where I would like to extract the received date of that email.

Is there a way to extract with Power Automate the reception date of the .MSG file and store it in the "Received" column.

I found a way to extract the date from a .EML message, it's in the textual format, but now how to extract the date from the .MSG file?

[image]

Comment: If you find a way to extract date from a EML, can you answer your own question here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/310364